# What's the right sintax to search for a X(6) format var in Progress 4gl?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

On the statement below I have an error telling me that attribute type is not compatible with. I consult database properties and this attribute format is x(6). Does anyone know which the right sintax to get it ? 
P.s. I already tried = '1', EQ 1, EQ '1', = "1" and EQ "1"

```
FOR EACH bd.tablename WHERE  bd.tablename.attribute = "1"
```

Comment: I don't see how you are getting this error unless the column is not a character column (which it should be if the format is x(6)).  EQ or = is fine... '1' or "1" is also fine for characters. We are missing part of the story here. Double check the column format and post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: One exception I thought about... RAW data types will also show a format of X(n). Don't check the default display format... check the data type.

Comment: Please use real code examples and provide actual error messages.  Fake examples are impossible to accurately evaluate.

Comment: When I  consult raw data type the format i See for my attribute is CHAR.

Comment: Format is meaningless... the only thing that matters is data type. If your column is defined as RAW it is a binary format similar to a BLOB and can't be treated as a character.

Answer (score 0):

When you say property/attribute, do you mean a field? If you're talking about buffer/table attributes, such as type, for example, the separator should be colon, this -> :

Not period (.), unlike most other OO languages.
But if you're talking about a field, TheMadDBA is correct, and you should check the data type, it's way safer than just the field format.
If you still have this issue, maybe provide more information and we can try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The code statement is:

```
FOR EACH multipos.mp_mvlj WHERE  multipos.mp_mvlj.mvl_codmov = 1  NO-LOCK:
```

The error is (translated from portuguese):

```
Incompatible Data type in expression or attribution
```